# MimeMail: issue with attachments

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, mime-mail

I'm using mimemail module in Drupal to send e-mails with attachments. The e-mails are correctly sent, but the attachments not. This is the code I use (I've just enabled the module):

```
$sender = 'mycompany@company.com';
$recipient = 'myemail@mail.com';
$subject = 'New order';
$body = 'Please, see the attachment.';
$plaintext = TRUE;
$headers = array();
$attachments[]=array(         
  'filepath' => 'invoices/sample.pdf',
  'filemime' => 'application/pdf',
);

mimemail($sender, $recipient, $subject, $body, $plaintext, $headers, $text = NULL, $attachments, $mailkey);
```

In order to be sure the path to the pdf attachment is correct I've written this line to download the attachment from browser and it works.

```
header('Location: invoices/sample.pdf');
```

Also,I've tried this alternative code. But still nothing...

```
$file = new stdClass();
$file->filename = 'sample.pdf';
$file->filepath = 'invoices/sample.pdf';
$file->filemime = 'application/pdf';
mimemail($sender, $recipient, $subject, $body, $plaintext, $headers, $text = NULL, array($file), $mailkey);
```

ps. i don't think this, but is maybe because my hosting disallow to send attachments ?
thanks

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute file path instead of `invoices/sample.pdf`?

Comment: yeah, I've tried all possible paths... the root of my website /invoices... also the complete one http://www.domain.com/invoices ... is the $attachments well declared and passed to milemail function ? I'm really stuck on this, argh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issue reports opened for the Mime Mail module.

In [Attachments specified with absolute local paths are not added](http://drupal.org/node/760080), the OP reports that attachments specified using absolute paths don't work; there is a proposed patch to solve the issue. In that issue, it's suggested to change the code to send an email with attachements from

```
header('Location: invoices/sample.pdf');

$sender = 'mycompany@company.com';
$recipient = 'myemail@email.com';
$subject = 'New order';
$body = 'Please, see the attachment.';
$plaintext = TRUE;
$headers = array();
$attachments[] = array(
  'filepath' => 'invoices/sample.pdf',
  'filemime' => 'mime/type',
);

mimemail($sender, $recipient, $subject, $body, $plaintext, $headers, $text = NULL, $attachments, $mailkey);
```

to

```
header('Location: invoices/sample.pdf');

$sender = 'mycompany@company.com';
$recipient = 'myemail@email.com';
$subject = 'New order';
$body = 'Please, see the attachment.';
$plaintext = TRUE;
$headers = array();
$attachments[] = array(
  'filepath' => 'invoices/sample.pdf',
  'filemime' => 'mime/type',
  'filename' => 'sample.pdf',
  'list' => TRUE,
);

mimemail($sender, $recipient, $subject, $body, $plaintext, $headers, $text = NULL, $attachments, $mailkey);
```

In [mimemail + smtp + attachments not working with attachments](http://drupal.org/node/855570), the OP reports that attachments are not shown when using SMTP; in the same report, another user reports that he is not using SMTP, but the attachements are not shown when the email is sent through Rules.

Comment: The correct function to call in Drupal, and that has the same effect of `header()`, is `drupal_set_header()`, which stores the set headers in a static variable, and returns the already set headers.